# PHP string with decimals to number

Tags: php, variables, integer

So when I try the following:

```
$a = '1.00';
$b = '1.01';

if($a < $b){
    print 'ok';
}
```

This works fine. But when I retrieve these variables from an xml file. the strings are EXACTLY the same, but for some reason, the if function doesn't work right. So I assume I have to convert the strings to a number. But when I do so, the decimals get removed.

Is my assumption correct? If so, how do i solve it?

If not, what's the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you converting them to a [double](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$a = (float) $a;
$b = (float) $b;
```

Related reading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: so what's the difference between float and floatval?

Comment: When converting an object to a float, `floatval` will generate a notice, casting to float won’t.

Answer (score -4):

Do it like this:

```php
floatval($string);
```

Comment: Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.